# What are possible causes for the flaps not deploying on a Cessna 172?

Tags: flaps, electrical-system, cessna-172

I would like to seek some expert opinion on why my flaps failed to deploy when I took it to Flaps 20.

I was turning from Downwind to Base when I took flaps 20 and noticed that my speed was creeping past 80kts even at idle power. My instructor took a look outside and that’s when we realised that the flaps were still at the UP position. We tried checking the circuit breaker for Flaps and the other switches, and everything else was normal.

We came in flapless until short finals when the flaps deployed to Flaps 10 when the switch was moved to the Flaps 30 position.

We did some checks on the ground and whenever we took Flaps down, static interference could be heard. It’s as if it was timed to happen the moment the flaps are extended. No static heard when the flaps are raised.

Any expert opinion would be appreciated as I would like to really understand what I am flying. I have checked the POH and it barely says anything, even the Electrics diagrams aren’t helping me diagnose why.

I’m a student pilot with barely 20 hours flight time.

Comment: ATIS on that day was: Temp 39 with M12 Crosswind. QNH1010.

Comment: So flaps anything 20 or less gave you no flaps at all, but once you selected flaps 30, you got what you should have had by selecting flaps 10? Did you hear static also when raising the flaps? Was the static related to the switch movement, or to the flaps movement?

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert on the C172, but for me the flaps switch (control) and the cabling all the way to the flaps actuation motors would definitely be a prime suspect along with whatever sits between the motors and the actual flaps...

Comment: @aCVn yes that’s right. The static noise only happens when the flaps start extending downwards. You could hear crackling noises that would be timed to happen at the same time when the flaps start to lower, as soon as you take a stage of flap.

Comment: @aCVn no static was heard when the flaps are being raised.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: What does youe mechanic say?

Comment: @vasin1987 I’ll check with them when they work on Monday.

Comment: Don't fly it like that, the aircraft should be taken out of service. The last thing you want is sudden flap deployment or asymmetric deployment on short final.

Comment: @RonBeyer is the C172 capable of asymmetric deployment? I figured both sides were mechanically linked.

Comment: @AEhere Yes, it is possible. The flaps are connected through pulleys and wires through turnbuckles and are mechanically linked, but if one is jammed and the wire breaks, one flap might work, and the other might not. Since the flap motor is in the right wing, it would be more likely that the right flap would work, and the left would not. [Here is at least one case of it happening](https://www.pilotsofamerica.com/community/threads/c172-asymmetrical-flap-deployment.73971/)

Comment: @RonBeyer TIL. Thanks for that, I can make it into a proper question if you feel like elaborating.

Comment: @shogunnyan any feedback?

Comment: @vasin1987 negative no fault found :/ back into service and flying normally somehow

Answer (score 5):

If the flap actuating motor is defective, you'll get exactly (or very close to) those symptoms, including the "interference" when the motor is operated. It could also be that the power connector to the motor was loose, damaged or corroded.